# Copying between workbooks and worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do a copy and paste of data in between workbooks and worksheets. I have the following codes but it seems to be taking up much time. I was wondering if there is any simpler way in copying?

```
    Sub Test1()

    Dim wb As Workbook, x As String, y As String, wb1 As Workbook

    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    If wb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then x = wb.Name
    Next wb

    Workbooks(x).Activate

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:E").Copy

    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select

    Workbooks(x).Activate
    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlNormal
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F:F").Copy
    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G:G").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
    Workbooks(x).Activate
    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlNormal

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some idea from JMAX and found a way which is as follows:

```
Sub test()
Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim vFile As Variant

'Set source workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
'Open the target workbook
vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xls", _
    1, "Select One File To Open", , False)
'if the user didn't select a file, exit sub
If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
Workbooks.Open vFile
'Set targetworkbook
Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook

'For instance, copy data from a range in the first workbook to another range in the other workbook
wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:B").Copy
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Some headsup:- Use

```
Sub Test1()
Application.Screenupdating = False
'yourcode
Application.Screenupdating = True
End Sub
```

in your code to execute it faster

for copy paste a short verion that can be used is

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F:F").Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G:G")
```

Instead of activating certain books try pasting directly to the destination as mentioned in the above code.

you can remove "ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized"

EDIT:- as per added comments

```
dim wb1 as workbook
dim wb2 as workbook
set wb1 = ("Filename.xlsx")
set wb2 = ("filename.xlsx")

wb1.sheetname.range("A1").copy wb2.sheetname.range("A1")
```

you can further decalre your sheetname as well

```
dim ws as worksheet
set ws = worksheets("Sheetname")
```

Edit as per second comment (add variable to newly opened workbook)

```
Dim path as variant
dim wsb as workbook

path = \\C:your path   ' not the sheet name
Set wsb = Workbooks.Open(filename:=myfolder & "\" & "filename".xlsm")
'your codes
```

Comment: thanks but what I am trying to do is to do a copy between workbooks that the reason why I make use of those cross activations of the books. In other words, my code is to activate the first book that will do copy and then paste the data in another book

Comment: Copy pasting in different workbook also works with above, you need to declare your workbooks like Dim wb1 as Workbook1.xls, dim wb2 as workbook2.xls and then wb1.sheetname.range().copy wb2.sheetname.range()....this should also work...

Comment: but the problem i have is there is no fixed name for the workbook as I am doing a weekly based excel file.. thanks for your input! :)